# Relating the deformation of Calabi-Yau metrics and the conformal quantum field theories

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, calabi-yau

(v2)

As I read e.g. [in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13945/why-is-compactification-restricted-to-toroids-calabi-yau-co), the nice holonomy group features of Calabi-Yau manifolds are valuable regarding supersymmetry (I suspect because it's a symmetry involving the target manifold, not only the fields?) for quantization. But moreover, their features also seem to turn up in questions regarding the defomration of one two-dimensional world sheet quantum field field theory to another. I see the introduction of operators in the Lagrangian etc. and it's reminiscent of renomralization (keyword: moduli space?). Then I read something about the beta function being zero, because it would be proportional to the Ricci curvature of the target manifold, which is zero for Calabi-Yau manifolds. And that's another argument, which speak for their consideration. (Remark: Maybe there is a broader spectrum of theories for which these questions don't make sense. I guess I'm talking about non-linear sigma models here.)

> In string theory, do you use the renormalization techniques as representations of the geometrical deformations?
>
> We get different theories for neightboring metrics right? How closely is the number of possible vacuum states is related to the number of Calabi-Yau metrics?

Comment: The question of renormalization in string theory is addressed in http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26827/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9340/.

Comment: This question isn't particularly well formulated.  What are you really trying to ask?