# Superstring theory and renormalization

Tags: string-theory, renormalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the renormalization group apply to string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/does-the-renormalization-group-apply-to-string-theory)
>   [Renormalization in string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26827/renormalization-in-string-theory)

QED and some quantum theories require renormalization techniques and take it as somehow granted.

I did not study string theories yet, but I would like to whether renormalization similar to QED and some quantum theories is required in superstring theory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26827/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9340/2451

Comment: Yes, in peturbative string theory. E.g. vacuum energy. This vacuum energy takes the form of $\frac{\ell_s\hbar}{c_0}\sum_{k=1}^nk$. This has to be renormalised using a Ramanujam sum, and renormalisedd to $-\frac{1}{12}$. However, recently in the past $\approx 20\operatorname{years}$ or so, during the end of the second superstring revolution, there has been an outbreak of something called "matrix models of string theory" which is non-peturbative and there, fore, does not need, clearly, any form, of renormalisation. Examples,: M(Atrix) theory (BFSS Matrix theory), Matrix String theory etc.