# Will a tiny particle size ensure that QFT's, and quantum gravity in particular, don't need renormalization?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity, perturbation-theory

If particles have an extended structure, as is for example the case in string theory, it seems that singularities will stay at bay.

They can't gather at one point and it seems a natural cut-off is introduced in the context of renormalization.

Are non-point-like particle structures the solution to a quantum gravity, like string theory claims to be? Is renormalization still needed?

Edit- What I'm actually interested in is the relation between a non-point-like particle structure and quantum gravity. Will the infinities associated with the point-like structure of gravitons leave the theory? It seems a point-like graviton can cause singularities in the spacetime metric, hence rendering the theory non-renormalizable. In the case of the other interactions the point-like nature of the particles doesn't influence the spacetime metric and the infinities can be swept under the carpet. But gravitons affect the spacetime metric, and it seems the "quantum foam" contains weird features like micro black holes or even tiny wormholes. Will finite sized graviton structures prevent this "boiling" of spacetime? Will gravity be renormalizable if we consider non-pointlike gravitons (as it is to a certain extent in string theory)? Or better, doesn’t need renormalization at all, since the small-distance/high-energy contributions vanish?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9340/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26827/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I think that you are attributing the string dimensions to the representations of a particle, and you are not aware that the particle identity , electrons, neutrinos etc (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle )  is  assigned to a vibration of the string, not the size. You should read the links given by quantum mechanics.